# The usage of would in "when a skeptic would deride their work"

Tags: past-tense, will-would

I'd like to know what "would" exactly means here? Please help me I couldn't figure it out no matter how much I tried. Thanks a lot.

> The Wright brothers didn't become distraught when a skeptic **would** deride their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Would,** the past tense of *will,* in part of its rôle as a modal verb, is used sometimes to describe *repeated* or *habitual* past actions. That is its use here. Compare Gray's *An elegy, wrote in a country church-yard,* from 1751:

> There at the foot of yonder nodding beech
>   His listless length at noontide **wou'd** he stretch

*Would* is most often used to indicate future obligation, intention, or prediction (*I would do that*). That is the *epistemic* use; but *would* still retains some of its original sense as the past tense of *will,* and partakes of *will's* original meaning of *want or desire.*

As John Lawler puts it [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50031/192771), this is *would* used in its function as "as the past tense of a deontic habitual use of *will.*" It is the "*deontic* sense of *would;* it involves desire and **will**ingness."

Thus, the sentence means:

> The Wright brothers didn't become distraught when a skeptic *habitually and repeatedly desired to* deride their work.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence can be reworded as the following:

> The Wright brothers didn't become distraught when a skeptic **derided** their work.

From this, we can see that "would" here means that the following verb is in past tense. It can sound more natural and/or elegant at times, which accounts for its prevalence.

Answer (score 1):

***[Would](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)*** in your sentence is used to suggest a intention  in a context that refers to the past:

> - (also 'd) ***used to refer to an intention from the point of view of the past:***
>
>   - *He said he would always love her* .
>   - *They promised that they would help.*
>   - *There was nobody left who **would (= was willing to)** do it.*
>   - *I asked him to move his car but he said he **wouldn't (= he refused).**

Cambridge Dictionary